# Got 3 heatsinks with my raspberry pi?

Tags: pi-3, hardware

I got 3 heatsinks with my raspberry pi 3 B+ which was ordered via my school. I got 2 small ones (both the size of the Ethernet chip) and a big one(size of SoC). So far websites always tell me to put the big one on the SoC and a small one on the ethernet chip. But where would I put a third one?

Comment: Pi3B+ doesn't really need any. I don't have any on mine.

Comment: I already got them so why not using them anyways?

Comment: Take care if you want to fit a hat - it may not fit over heatsinks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image from somewhere.

[image: Placement of three heatsinks]

So number three goes on the other side of the PCB?

Comment: Ok, interesting. But what's this orange thing supposed to be?

Comment: All I know is I also have three, and this picture is connected in some way. I never tried them, as overheating has not been a problem for me. I imagine the orange is adhesive tape? Not sure why it is shown like that.

Comment: ok, strange. Then I'll just keep it with the 2 first ones for now..

Comment: 'Orange' one is a copper square of metal - so that cases still fit.

Answer (score 0):

I have three heatsinks, one on main and one each on Ethernet and Bluetooth (the orange one as per [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w84np.png) in [Tomas By's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96483/got-3-heatsinks-with-my-raspberry-pi#answer-96485) above, on the underside).

Just had mine 2 days ago.